# Show Custom message when Weblogic server is down

Tags: jsp, http-status-code-404, weblogic12c, configure, f5

I work on a java web application. I use `Weblogic 12c` in my machine.

We have got a requirement of showing a custom message when we attempt to access a `URL` when the `Weblogic` service is down for maintenance instead of the usual `500` or `404 "Page Not Found"`. I'm not using the `Apache layer`. I'm directly using `F5 layer` instead.

I just learned that the `F5 layer` will take care of redirecting to this new page which has the custom message. But how do we configure that? Is there a specific configuration file (some kind of an `xml` file) where we would have to define this information?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a redirection when all pool members are down with an iRule, or with a local traffic policy. The iRule can redirect to a different host/uri or host that sorry page locally on the BIG-IP. [Here's an example](https://devcentral.f5.com/codeshare/ltm-maintenance-page-lite) of the latter, but can easily be customized for the former.